# Pumping Lemma for $L=\left\{0^i 1^{j} \mid \gcd(i,j) = 1\right\}$

Tags: computer-science, regular-language

Let $L=\left\{0^i 1^{j} \mid \gcd(i,j) = 1\right\}$ I want to prove that this is not a regular language, but I am having trouble finding a string I can pump resulting in the string not being in the language. Ideally, rather than a full solution, I'd like suggestions for a string that I could use in this proof. I've played with the idea of setting $j = 2$ and $i = 2n+1$, but I don't think that would work.

Comment: Does the exercise explicitly ask you to do it using the Pumping Lemma? Because I personally think that it is almost always more convenient to use the characterization of regular languages using **Myhill-Nerode** equivalence classes (if you are familiar with those).

Comment: It explicitly asks for the pumping lemma. It is one of the "!!" challenge problems in $\textit{An Introduction to Automata Theory, Languages, and Computation}$  and we haven't talked about Myhill-Nerode equivalences classes there, nor have I worked with them before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p$ be a prime number greater than the pumping length, and try $0^{p-1}1^p$. Show that when you pump up, you get something of the form $0^{p-1+kr}1^p$ for some $r$ such that $1\le r<p$, and show that there is a $k\ge 1$ such that $kr-1$ is a multiple of $p$, i.e., such that $kr\equiv 1\pmod p$.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more on the last step, about how to show that $kr-1$ is a multiple of $p$?

Comment: @ejz: Let me ask first whether you’ve had any elementary number theory or group theory.

Comment: I have not had experience with those

Comment: @ejz: Okay; that makes it a little harder. I’ll add a bit.

Comment: @ejz: Let me ask one more question: are you familiar with the Euclidean algorithm for finding the greatest common divisor of two integers?

Comment: I just read about it online, but I have no experience using it. I think I understand the general progression

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30998/discussion-between-ejz-and-brian-m-scott).